# Problema al desplegar elementos de html con toogle

Tags: jquery, html

Estoy tratado de mostrar y ocultar varios `div`s que tienen la misma clase. Al hacer clic sobre la clase `icon-plus` esta despliega el contenido oculto y cambia su clase por `icon-minus`.

Al volver hacer clic oculta el `div` y vuelve a cambiar a la clase `icon-plus`. Hasta ahorita he conseguido hacer esto, pero tengo un detalle: Al hacer click en cualquiera de los `div`s me los despliega todos.

Este es el código que tengo, también agrego que los `div` y la estructura de HTML la estoy generando desde un *json*.

Código que muestra y oculta `div`s

```
var clic = 1;

    $('body').delegate('.accordion_header','click', function() {
        $('.accordion_content').slideToggle('slow');
        if(clic==1){
            $(this).find('.accordion_icon').addClass('fa-minus');
            $(this).find('.accordion_icon').removeClass('fa-plus');
            clic = clic + 1;
        }else{
            $(this).find('.accordion_icon').removeClass('fa fa-minus');
            $(this).find('.accordion_icon').addClass('fa fa-plus');
            clic = 1;
        }
    });
```

Código que genera el html

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
            
               $.getJSON('json/bolsaTrabajo.json', function(jd) {
                    $.each(jd, function(i, item) {                        

                        $('.accordion').append('<div class="accordion_group"><div class="accordion_header"><span class="accordion_icon fa fa-plus"></span>' + item.vac + '</div><div class="accordion_content"><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12"><table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><th>FECHA</th></tr><tr><td>'+ item.fecha +'</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span6"><table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><th>NOMBRE DE LA VACANTE</th></tr><tr><td class="nombreDeVacante">'+item.vac+'</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="span6"><table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><th>ESCOLARIDAD</th></tr><tr><td>'+item.esc+'</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><th>CONOCIMIENTOS</th></tr><tr><td><ul>'+item.conoc+'</ul></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><th>HABILIDADES / COMPETENCIAS</th></tr><tr><td><ul>'+item.habiCono+'</ul></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><th>ACTIVIDADES</th></tr><tr><td><ul>'+item.act+'</ul></td></tr></tbody></table> <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><th>OFRECEMOS</th></tr><tr><td>'+item.ofre+'</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="contact-wrapper"></div></div></div>');

                    });
               });  
         });
</script>
<div class="accordion">
</div>
```

Agradecería si alguien me ayudara con esto; llevo varios días haciéndolo y no lo he conseguido, de ante mano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta línea

```
$('.accordion_content').slideToggle('slow');
```

Estás desplegando/ocultando todos los elementos que tengan la clase accordion_content.

Prueba cambiándola por

```
$(this).slideToggle('slow');
```

Para solo aplicar la operación sobre el acordeón clickeado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, probe cambiando la linea, pero ahora al dar click hace el toogle sobre sobre la clase accordion_header, lo cual provoca que ya no vea el div con dicha clase

Comment: Tambien intente hacerlo de esta forma pero tampoco funciono.                                                                                               $(this).find('.accordion_content').slideToggle('slow');

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, investigando un poco por diversos foros encontre como resulverlo, les comparto, como: $(this).nextUntil(':not(.accordion_content)').slideToggle();